# Javascript: Table with checkboxes filters

Tags: javascript

I am working on this [website](http://weierweg-liestal.ch/wohnen/) and as you can see i have a table of content with some Filters on top to filter the results. Basically you click on the checkboxes and you can filter the results between `rows`

I am actually trying to use this `script` to try to filter the results but does not works

```
$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer4", function() {
  $("#tableID tr.zimmer4").toggle(!this.checked);
});

$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer3", function() {
  $("#tableID tr.zimmer3").toggle(!this.checked);
});

$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer2", function() {
  $("#tableID tr.zimmer2").toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Zimmer
            <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <form class="filter">
    <input id="zimmer4" class="unchecked" type="checkbox">4.5
    <br>
    <input id="zimmer3" class="unchecked" type="checkbox">3.5
    <br>
    <input id="zimmer2" class="unchecked" type="checkbox">2.5
    <br>
  </form>
</ul>
</span>
```

HTML Table Rows:

```
<div id="wrap" class="tabelle">
<table class="table" id="tableID">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Wohnung</th>
<th>Zimmer</th>
<th>Stockwerk</th>
<th>Nettomiete</th>
<th>Bruttomiete</th>
<th>PDF</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="row1 row2OG row3OG zimmer3 zimmer2 range1 range2 range3 range5">
<td>1.001</td>
<td>4.5</td>
<td>EG / 1. OG</td>
<td>2252</td>
<td>2500</td>
<td><a href="/table/pdfs/01.001.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/img/pdf.png" alt=""></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

use this code,

final code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <style>
        .hid {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
       <select id="zimmer">
           <option value="all">Select Zimmer</option>
            <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
             <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
             <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
        </select>
        <table id="tab">
            <tr><th>Wohnung</th><th>Zimmer</th><th>Stockwerk</th></tr>
            <tr class="2.5"><td>xxx</td><td>2.5</td><td>www</td></tr>
             <tr class="4.5"><td>xx</td><td>4.5</td><td>www</td></tr>
             <tr class="3.5"><td>aaa</td><td>3.5</td><td>www</td></tr>
             <tr class="3.5"><td>qqq</td><td>3.5</td><td>www</td></tr>
            <tr class="3.5"><td>fff</td><td>3.5</td><td>www</td></tr>
             <tr class="4.5"><td>ppp</td><td>4.5</td><td>www</td></tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            var ele = document.getElementById("zimmer");
            var rows = document.getElementById("tab").rows;
            ele.addEventListener('change',filterTable);
            function filterTable() {
                for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){
                    if(rows[i].classList.contains(this.value))
                        rows[i].classList.remove("hid");
                    else if (this.value == "all")
                        rows[i].classList.remove("hid");
                    else
                        rows[i].classList.add("hid");

                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @developppping when checked checkbox 3.5 or 2.5  so  row deleted.what is your question?

Comment: @developppping copy all my code in your editor and run it.if does not works,Ask your question more clearly.

Comment: the problem is that i am using exactly the same code i used here http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/ and does not works...

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from your example, it should work.
Also check the console on your site, it gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I created a fiddle from your code, but editted a small thing: I assume you want to display the rows wich checkboxes are selected. Instead of hiding them when you select the checkbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/pp34rxhp/1/

Comment: Hi, i tried but does not works. And anyway i need to hide the row with "3.5" or "2.5" when the 4.5 checkbox is selected.

Comment: When you open the fiddle, the rows aren't toggled when you check/uncheck the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes i can see the rows, then when you uncheck the checkbox they are are hided... i want to "filter" the rows. For example when "4.5" checkbox is selected the "3.5" and "2.5" rows are hided...

Comment: That's another question. So my fiddle solves the problem you state in your question?

Comment: No because i tried to create a sample page with your code and does not works. I am using Wordpress and i am loading the JS using a plugin...